# Dismiss fragment in onPause

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've received a crash for my app with an IllegalStateException on Android 4.2 (my app supports 3.1+). After a bit of digging in the docs, I found that there is no warranty about the order of calls of `onPause()` and `onSaveInstanceState()`. The only thing you know is that the `onSaveInstanceState()` is called before `onStop()`. So my question: what is the best thing to do in this case?

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (connectionInProgress) {
        cd = ConnectingDialog.findOrCreate(getFragmentManager());
        cd.show(getFragmentManager(), ConnectingDialog.TAG);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (cd != null)
        cd.dismiss();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into this before.  The problem is, once android saves the activity's instance state, they don't allow that state to be changed.  Adding, replacing, removing fragments of that activity would be breaking this law, so Android considers the activity to be in an "illegal" state. ;)

The fix could be as simple as the following:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState() {
    mHasSavedInstance = true;
    super.onSaveInstanceState();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() { 
    super.onResume();
    mHasSavedInstance = false;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() { 
    if (cd != null && !mHasSavedInstance)
        cd.dismiss();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: It could work but I think it's not safe because if onSaveInstanceState can be run in parallel with onPause and the only sync point is onStop() you could miss the flag.

Comment: Don't worry about that, the onSaveInstanceState should be called from the main thread for your problem, so should be synchronous.  If user is active on the front activity of the backstack, and some activity in the backstack is about to be reclaimed by the system, onSaveInstanceState() might run in another thread other than the UI-thread in that case, but your flag would still save you since your onPause() has ran much before the system's call.